# How to make a deep copy of a GIF with the PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to load a GIF using the Python Imaging Library and then duplicate it so that I am not operating on the original. My code is as follows:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
from PIL import GifImagePlugin

inputimg = Image.open(sys.argv[2])
outputimg = inputimg.copy()
print (inputimg.n_frames)
print (outputimg.n_frames)
```

When this is run, I get this:

```
318
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "colorcorrect.py", line 20, in <module>
    print (outputimg.n_frames)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'n_frames'
```

It is therefore clear that the `outputimg` does not have `n_frames`, and `Image.copy()` is therefore not respecting the fact that the original image was a GIF and is actually shedding data when run.

What is the recommended way to create a deep copy of the original image, maintaining all of the metadata?

EDIT: To clarify, my goal is as follows: Load in a GIF, and perform changes on a copy of that GIF to write to disk as a separate GIF. The output will be a single file with the changes that is distinct from the input file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can use a simple way by using shutil :

```
import shutil
from PIL import Image
one='original.gif'
two='duplicate.gif'
shutil.copy(one, two)
img1=Image.open(one)
img2=Image.open(two)
print(img1.n_frames,img2.n_frames)
```

Comment: I don't think he wants copy gifs physically, he wants to copy content inside his code

Comment: This answer looks like works, but it does so by circumventing the problem in the question altogether. I'll give it a try since it'll have the outcome I'm looking for, but apologies in advance for not marking it as accepted since it doesn't answer the question.